# Why is X-Forwarded-For header not getting set by node-express proxy?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I have a single node file which does the following:

It listens on two ports: 80 and 443 (for https).
It redirects connections on 80 to 443.

And on 443 is a reverse proxy that does a round-robin redirects to several local servers over plain http.

The problem that I have is that in the actual target servers, I am unable to get the actual remote IP address of the browser.
I get the address of the reverse proxy.
The request is made by the reverse proxy, so thats expected I guess.

So, I did the following in the reverse proxy (only relevant code lines shown):

```
    proxy = httpProxy.createServer();

    var https_app = express();
    https.createServer(sslCerts, https_app).listen(443, function () {
     ...
    });


    https_app.all("/",function(req, res) {
        ...
        //res.append('X-Forwarded-For',req.connection.remoteAddress);
        proxy.web(req,res, {target: local_server});
        ...
    }
```

I need to do something like res.append('X-Forwarded-For',req.connection.remoteAddress) to the proxy server.. in its request header.  The issue of setting the address is secondary. I first need to set the header itself which can be read by the target server.  The proxy itself does not set this header, which I think it should by default. Or should it? Or does it and I am doing something wrong to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your definition of `proxy`, but I'm assuming it is same as the following code, using `express-http-proxy`. I expect this alternative method will work for you:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

var myProxy= proxy('localhost:443', {
    forwardPath: function (req, res) {
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }
});
```

And then simply:

```
app.use("/*", myProxy);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using  the  proxy from https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy and I think that I got the answer from that site's documentation titled "Setup a stand-alone proxy server with proxy request header re-writing" I missed it earlier. I will try it later and hope it works.

Comment: Just forgot about this post altogether. I fixed the problem which was due to something silly I was doing in the proxy server code. Upvoted your answer and yes, I think that your solution would have worked if I had been using express-http-proxy so I am accepting the answer.